# How to view all the privileges of a role

Tags: sql, oracle

How to view all the privileges of a particular role in Oracle?

For example:

```
Role           Privileges
Connect        select
Connect        insert
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`role_sys_privs`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2443.htm).

According to the documentation:

> `ROLE_SYS_PRIVS` describes system privileges granted to roles. Information is provided only about roles to which the user has access.

So this will get you the list:

```
select *
from   role_sys_privs
where  role = :role
```

Comment: This works fine,but i couldn't get it work for user defined roles.

Comment: @RamKumar: I see custom roles defined in `role_sys_privs`. Are you sure you have the appropriate privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns all object privileges (not including column-specific privileges) granted to the specified user:

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE, GRANTABLE FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS
        WHERE GRANTEE = 'JWARD';
```

[resourse](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#15665)

Answer (score 0):

For role privileges granted to role check View ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS. For all roles granted to grantee check DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will help you.

```
ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS     -describes the roles granted to other roles. 
ROLE_SYS_PRIVS      -describes system privileges granted to roles.
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS      -describes table privileges granted to roles. 

select * from ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');    
select * from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS  where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS  where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');
```

To know more [Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840745/how-to-check-the-privileges-ddl-dml-dcl-on-objects-assigned-to-schema-roles-i).

Thanks!