# How to check the privileges (DDL,DML,DCL) on objects assigned to Schema, Roles in oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, privileges

Most of the time we struggle with silly things to get the detail of privileges on Schema, Role and their Objects and try to find some easy way to get all the detail about it along with there pseudo queries code to generate grant statements in bulk for further execution. So here we are to get it.

Answer (score 6):

**A little brief about data dictionary view prefix:**

```
ALL_    -Describes PUBLIC Object grants.
USER_   -Describes current user Object grants.
DBA_    -Describes all object grants in the database.
```

**Useful views information:**

```
ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS     -describes the roles granted to other roles. 
ROLE_SYS_PRIVS      -describes system privileges granted to roles.
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS      -describes table privileges granted to roles. 
DBA_ROLE_PRIVS      -describes the roles granted to all users and roles in the database.
DBA_SYS_PRIVS       -describes system privileges granted to users and roles.
DBA_TAB_PRIVS       -describes all object grants in the database.
DBA_COL_PRIVS       -describes all column object grants in the database.
```

To know more about **PRIVS** views visit [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/catalog_views?preference=PRIVS#list_of_items).

**Queries:**

*-About user/schema status*

```
select username,account_status, created from dba_users where username in ('SCOTT');
```

*-Check the assigned roles to role and schema*

```
select * from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT','RESOURCE');
```

*-Check the role privileges*

```
select * from ROLE_ROLE_PRIVS where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');    
select * from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS  where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');
select * from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS  where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');

Pseudo Code:
select 'grant '||privilege||' to ROLE_SLAVE;' from ROLE_SYS_PRIVS where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');
select 'grant '||privilege||' to ROLE_SLAVE;' from ROLE_TAB_PRIVS where role in ('RESOURCE','CONNECT');
```

*-Check privileges of granted objects for schema*

```
select * from DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT');
select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT');
select * from DBA_COL_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT');

Pseudo Code: 
select 'grant '||privilege||' to SCOTT_SLAVE;' from DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT');
select 'grant '||privilege||' on '||owner||'.'||table_name||' to SCOTT_SLAVE;' from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT');
select 'grant '||privilege||' ('||column_name||') '||' on '||owner||'.'||table_name||' to SCOTT_SLAVE;' from DBA_COL_PRIVS where grantee in ('SCOTT');
```

***Thank You!***